# MS Remote Desktop - drives not mapping - broken by Sierra update 10.12.2?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, remote-desktop

MacOS Sierra running the Microsoft Remote Desktop version `8.0.36` application connecting to various different MS Windows servers.

Was working fine,  but following the Sierra update 10.12.2 the drives are not mapping,  regardless of the target OS.

Current workaround is to use remote desktop in a VM,  but this is really inconvenient.

*Edit: Feb 2017*

Another Sierra update,  another broken RDP client.  Microsoft finally updated their RDP client in early January to fix this problem.  Now the Sierra 10.12.3 update's come along and broken it.  So no drive mappings again.

The beta RDP client has too many problems -- I just need a working RDP client -- so have to resort to using a VM running Windosw and it's RDP client.

*Edit: Jan 2018*

Seems that the High Sierra update on my Mac has broken the remote directory sharing again.  "Microsoft Remote Desktop" version 8.0.43

Updating the "beta" to version 8.2.41 enables me to connect and the drives are mapped.

Checking the Mac Application Store and they've released a new version of "Remote Desktop" (obligatory skipping of version 9 - why do they hate number nine?);  now version 10.1.1.   **This works**

Comment: I'd try the new beta 8.2, it's a lot better in many respects - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/03/30/remote-desktop-client-preview-for-mac-supports-multiple-monitors-and-more/

Comment: Worked perfectly;  add this as the answer so I can mark it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always got to be worth trying the new v8.2 version, currently in beta. I've been using it myself for quite some time & it's a lot better than the current release v8.0 in many respects.

MS Technet blog: [Remote Desktop Client Preview for Mac supports multiple monitors and more](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/03/30/remote-desktop-client-preview-for-mac-supports-multiple-monitors-and-more/)

Download: https://rink.hockeyapp.net/apps/5e0c144289a51fca2d3bfa39ce7f2b06/

Highlights -

> **Multiple monitor support**
>
> The preview app now supports the ability to use multiple monitors in
>   your remote session. You can enable multiple monitors for a desktop
>   connection from the additional options.
>
> **Copy and Paste files**
>
> In addition to supporting copy/paste of text and images, the preview
>   app now supports copy/paste of files so that you can transfer files
>   into and out of the remote session using both Command X/C/V and CTRL
>   X/C/V.
>
> **Updates to the keyboard**
>
> We’ve changed how the Beta app keyboard works to behave exactly like
>   the Remote Desktop client store app. The Beta app initially used a new
>   implementation of the keyboard; however, many of you reported that
>   this new keyboard introduced several issues with typing into apps like
>   the Hyper-v console and typing certain language characters. The Beta
>   app will continue to support both Command X/C/V and Ctrl X/C/V to copy
>   and paste between the local desktop and remote session. Use the Beta
>   app Help->Report an issue option to share your feedback about the
>   keyboard. [Learn more about how the keyboard works in a remote session.](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=760852&clcid=0x409)

Comment: Some small quirks on the beta version - differences with the current live version and it doesn't import the live version's setings;  but drive mapping works

Comment: @Tetsujin Where do you get the v8.2 beta version? The provided link is (currently) broken.

Comment: @Matthias - link tested & working for me. Direct link to download page is at https://rink.hockeyapp.net/apps/5e0c144289a51fca2d3bfa39ce7f2b06/ [hockeyapp is an MS site, so quite safe] Note; the current beta has a CPU issue if you leave it running for a long time 24-48h or so, I'd expect next version will fix it, they're usually pretty good.

Comment: Now the link works. Thanks for the quick reply. Folder redirection works with 8.2